# Duplicating class forbidden to run app. How to fix it?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

This errors shows up on terminal and I have checked everything since yesterday trying to find the duplicated dependencies but I couldn't find it.

This is the error:

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzik found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-17.5.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.5.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_core: 0.5.0
  cloud_firestore:
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
  location: 3.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.27+3
  font_awesome_flutter: 8.4.0
  geolocator: ^5.1.2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  appodeal_flutter: ^0.5.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.2
  intro_slider: ^2.3.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
  translator: ^0.1.5
  loading: ^1.0.2
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  beauty_textfield: ^0.0.1
  snaplist: ^0.1.8
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
  geoflutterfire: 2.2.1
  path_provider: ^1.6.18
  image: ^2.1.18
  uuid: ^2.2.2
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  share: ^0.6.5+2
```

Comment: Try `flutter clean` in your terminal, then run again.

Comment: Hi there @Zeus, unfortunately It didn't work.

Comment: I think you didn't complete configuration of some packages, particularly firebase related.